# How to accelerate the speed of this pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Pandas masters, here I have a question for you.

I am writing a function to convert the IP addresses to geolocation. I use a CSV file from IP2LOCATION as the lookup table. The lookup table looks like this:

|  | ip_start | ip_end | country_code | country_name | state_name | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 16777215 | - | - | - | - |
| 1 | 16777216 | 16777471 | US | United States of America | California | Los Angeles |
| 2 | 16777472 | 16778239 | CN | China | Fujian | Fuzhou |
| 3 | 16778240 | 16779263 | AU | Australia | Victoria | Melbourne |
| 4 | 16779264 | 16781311 | CN | China | Guangdong | Guangzhou |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2907906 | 3758094336 | 3758095359 | HK | Hong Kong | Hong Kong | Hong Kong |
| 2907907 | 3758095360 | 3758095871 | CN | China | Fujian | Fuzhou |
| 2907908 | 3758095872 | 3758096127 | SG | Singapore | Singapore | Singapore |
| 2907909 | 3758096128 | 3758096383 | AU | Australia | Queensland | Brisbane |
| 2907910 | 3758096384 | 4294967295 | - | - | - | - |

And I have 1.4M IP addresses in a dataframe. Now I want to traverse the DataFrame and lookup the city and country information. I did the following tests.

#### Test1

```
def get_city(ip_value, ip_lookup=ip_lookup):
    cond = (ip_value >= ip_lookup['ip_start']) & (ip_value < ip_lookup['ip_end'])
    match = ip_lookup.loc[cond]
    return pd.Series({'country': match['country_name'].item(), 'state': match['state_name'].item(), 'city': match['city_name'].item()})

df.loc[:10000, 'ip_value'].apply(get_city)
```

It took me 2 minutes 30 seconds to lookup only 10,000 IPs.

#### Test2

```
country_names = []
state_names = []
city_names = []

for _, ip_value in df.loc[:10000, 'ip_value'].iteritems():
    cond = (ip_value >= ip_lookup['ip_start']) & (ip_value < ip_lookup['ip_end'])
    match = ip_lookup.loc[cond]
    country_names.append(match['country_name'].item())
    state_names.append(match['state_name'].item())
    city_names.append(match['city_name'].item())
```

The speed of this code is almost the same as the previous one.

#### Test3

In this test, I set the 'ip_start' and 'ip_end' as indexes in 'ip_lookup' DataFrame.

```
ip_lookup.set_index(['ip_start', 'ip_end'], inplace=True)
ip_lookup.loc[(ip_lookup.index.get_level_values('ip_start') <= 1709327025) & (ip_lookup.index.get_level_values('ip_end') > 1709327025)]
```

This code works. But it is much slower than the previous two. It took 65ms to lookup only one IP.

#### Test4

In this test I use Dask.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df1 = dd.from_pandas(df.loc[:10000, 'ip_value'], npartitions=20)

def get_city(ip_value, ip_lookup=ip_lookup):
    cond = (ip_value >= ip_lookup['ip_start']) & (ip_value < ip_lookup['ip_end'])
    match = ip_lookup.loc[cond]
    return pd.Series({'country': match['country_name'].item(), 'state': match['state_name'].item(), 'city': match['city_name'].item()})

df1 = df1.apply(get_city, meta={'country': 'object', 'state': 'object', 'city': 'object'})
df1.compute()
```

This code is a little bit faster. It took 55 seconds to execute.

I need your help, I have 1.4M IP address to lookup. I really need to accelerate it. Any idea to make it? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but it may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you want to find the index faster than dataframe broadcast. try `bisect.bisect_left`, once you get the index than you could use `df.iloc` to get the geo location. in you case, you only need to get `ip_start` and check the left

```py
import bisect
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = np.sort(np.random.randint(100000, size=10000))
%time bisect.bisect_left(lst, 50)
CPU times: user 22 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 22 µs
Wall time: 25.3 µs

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['a'])
%time df[(df.a >30)&(df.a<60)] 
CPU times: user 2.03 ms, sys: 881 µs, total: 2.91 ms
Wall time: 2.51 ms
```

Comment: It will be faster if you don't use numpy data structures I believe

Comment: Thank you Galaxyan. I tested, it was fast.

Comment: @StevenLi :) yeah